# build app which scans barcodes and sends info to google sheet

Tags: barcode, google-sheets-api

Total newbie here but I have a question. We are trying to simplify a second hand book sale and want to build an app which allows parents to scan the barcode of books they want to sell then send this barcode, along with their name and email address (plus maybe a few other questions) to a Google Sheet.

A) is it possible to do this.
B) Any pointers to get started?

Comment: A) Anything is possible. B) You'll find everything you need (including libraries for scanning bar codes) on google.

Comment: Visit github for some samples. Here is an [example program](https://github.com/hyperoslo/BarcodeScanner) for barcode scanning from github. Also to learn more about barcode, you can visit [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode). For further references, you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is for python code

a) Yes, this is very possible
b)
You are going to need a bar-code scanner that can be connected to a computer and will then, somehow, have to enable this to input into python variables.

In terms of adding to google sheets, it is very possible to do this via Googles current API - if this sounds like jumble, there are plenty of guides at there for doing this in various 'easy' ways.

Here is some basic code to help you get started: (Haven't had the time to test it, and apologies if it is not relevant as I do not know how good you are at python.)

```
import time
```

class barcode:
    def **init**(self):
        self.code = int()

```
def getBarcode(self):
    print("Insert code to get barcode here. Assign barcode to variable: self.barcode")

    if self.barcode != None or self.barcode != "":
        return self.barcode()
    else:
        return False



def getDetails(self):
    name = input("Enter your full name: ")
    email = input("Enter your email address: ")
    return [name, email]

def sendInfo(self, barcode, details):
    name = details[0]
    email = details[1]
    barcode = self.barcode

    print("ENTER CODE HERE TO SUBMIT TO GOOGLE SHEETS")


def main(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        barcode = self.getBarcode()

        if barcode != False:
            details = self.getDetails()
            self.sendInfo(barcode, details)
```

If you need more help, or are worse at python than I expect, feel free to comment below.

Extra:
- Haven't had the chance to check it out or check its full relevance however this may help you: https://gist.github.com/JoachimL/1629f701fdb38427091710fc0caef67d